# ASP.NET Core 2.0 вынос Identity в DataLayer с использованием EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

Кто-нибудь делал что-то похожее? Ничего не нашел сам. Я планирую разделить проект на 3 уровня(Presentation, Business, Data). Авторизацию не выносить в отдельную базу, а использовать все в одной(со всеми остальными таблицами). При этом сохранить всю функциональность Identity на уровне Presentation и миграции тоже.

Comment: Что-то непонятно что вы хотите и в чём вопрос.

Comment: К примеру создаю приложение MVC с использованием индивидуальной авторизации по дефолту. Система мне сразу лепит контекст базы данных от IdentityFramework. Я её хочу вынести в Data Layer - c проекта её надо полностью удалить и сделать бессвязной, то есть организовать связь через Business layer. Вопрос большой - может у кого примерчик будет, я бы посмотрел. Пока я смог сделать 3 слоя, но без Identity.

Comment: Identity это часть проекта, зачем ее выносить наружу? Просто сделайте в отдельном проекте отдельный доступ к этой же базе, в чем проблема-то?